# Microwave on Pesach

Tags: halacha, chametz-leaven, appliances, stringency-chumrah, kashering-kosherization

A friend told me that his family will kasher his microwave in general (ie if non-kosher food was heated up in it) but will not kasher it for Pesach, letting it lie dormant instead. Does anyone have a **source** for such a distinction? (Let's also assume the tray can be covered, so the issue is only with the microwave itself.)

I know people are generally overly machmir (stringent) when it comes to chametz. I'm looking for a source for this particular distinction.

Comment: Re: the tray -- it's not that easy to cover. You certainly can't do so with tinfoil. Most people (I think) just get rid of the tray, which you don't actually need, or buy a new one for Pesach

Comment: I know that per Maran Yosef Qaro the concept of eino ben yomo applies to Pesah and therefore if one let's the microwave lie dormant for more than a day then food from it can be eaten during Pesah.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wanted to know, *why* some people might be machmir on this:

From [InstituteforDayanim.com](http://www.institutefordayanim.com/DisplayQuestion.asp?ID=136)

> Kashering a microwave for Pesach is impossible since only metal or wood can be kashered for Pesach. Although one can kasher plastic the rest of the year, one should not do so for Pesach. The inside of a microwave is generally not metal and is thus not kasherable.

It goes on to give a method to test if the microwave *has* absorbed any ta'am (even lifgam), and if it hasn't, it says it may be used. However, this that it can't be kashered, and that the only way to use it is if you're *sure* it hasn't absorbed anything, may be why some are machmir.

---

From [teach613.org](http://www.teach613.org/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=131&Itemid=57)

> Although many people will not kasher a microwave for Pesach because it has plastic components and because it is hard to clean properly, if you choose to kasher it the process is as follows. ...

(Plastic [can not be kashered](http://www.teach613.org/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=131&Itemid=57) for Pesach.)

Comment: Intersting. I wonder why they limit it to metal and wood? I know the Rama is machmir by glass, but that doesn't necasarily set the general rule.

Comment: @DoubleAA At the bottom of this [Star-K article](http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-passover-kashering.htm) it gives a list of materials that can't be kashered for Pesach. Among them, porcelain, stoneware, and plastic.

Comment: Hmmm...You've presented particularly perplexing passover pottery precepts! I will have to look into this further. Thanks!

Comment: @DoubleAA The second link I just edited in says that you _can_ kasher stone for Pesach. Either way, this is certainly a good reason for some to be nervous about using microwaves.

Comment: First link is dead.

Comment: Other two links don't go where they used to, it seems

Comment: The cRc [disagrees](http://www.crcweb.org/toveling.php) with the Star-K about plastic.