# Double Wrapping on Pesach

Tags: halacha, passover, cooking-bishul, chametz-leaven, appliances

I have always understood that one may use a non-kosher microwave for kosher food by double (or triple) wrapping the said food while cooking it. May one use the same procedure for cooking on Pesach in a microwave oven that's normally used for Chametz year-round?

Sources, please.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15191/759

Answer (score 3):

The Mishna Brura ([247:1 sv. 13](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%9E%D7%96)) And Shulchan Aruch HaRav (O.C. [247:10](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh3/1/447/10)) both permit covering as a way of avoiding the issue of smell, which is one of the issues that [the double covering is designed to avoid](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9297/whats-the-halachic-advantage-of-double-or-triple-wrapping-food).

So it would seem that according to those sources, yes, double covering would work.

Comment: "which is what the double covering is designed to avoid" can you source that? Do the cited MB and SAHR require two coverings or one to avoid the issue of smell?

Comment: @DoubleAA, they only speak of one covering. I added a link to another M.Y. question as the source.

Comment: When I brought this question to my rav last Pesach, he told me that double-wrapping was sufficient to serve as a barrier between the kosher l'Pesach food and the chametzdik (or treif) oven.

Comment: I would be really surprised if the standard practices for kashrus of year-round food apply to Pesach, where even the tiniest amount of chometz in food is not m'vatel and is a serious aveira. Can you provide a source that double-covering is sufficient to maintain Pesach kashrus? Wouldn't any chometz managing to escape through the double cover still be a major issue? Is there any reason besides lo bashamayim hi that you could be forgiven for that?

Comment: @SAH, my sources are in the answer. The discussion in 247 is about Pesach, not about year-round.

Comment: @Yishai Thanks for pointing that out. Sorry