# Can you double wrap chametz food in the oven before Pesach?

Tags: technology, chametz-leaven

I am going largely by hearsay on this...

Two reliable rabbis have told me that if you want to heat kosher food in a non-kosher oven, you can double wrap the food in foil and heat it in the oven, and your food remains kosher.

Can this method be used for chametz food? In other words, say the oven has been koshered for Pesach. Someone wants to keep it Kosher for Pesach. But, he has chametz food that he wants to heat before Pesach. Can he double wrap the chametz food in foil and heat it and still leave the oven Kosher for Pesach?

Regarding this, does chametz have any rules that are different than kosher food the rest of the year?

Comment: Duplicate? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/57170/4940

Comment: @magicker72 Looks like it. I'm VTC my own question.

Comment: One is an oven and the other is a microwave oven, but if you're happy with the closure, DanF, I'll close it.

Comment: @msh210 I'm surprised that there would be a concern with microwaves to begin with, as from many opinions that I have read (OU, for one), microwaves can be koshered very easily. I would have assumed that this technique is more of a concern with a conventional oven.

Comment: @DanF a microwave is a concern if one wants to use a communal, non-kosher one.

Comment: @msh210 Ah! Didn't think of that possibility. I'm a bit squeamish about even having a kosher restaurant heat my food in their nuker. That's my own shtick.